# How to sort the records based on month(June to May) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to display the records starting june month to may using mysql.

My table is

```
id    | subjects   |   from         |   to             |
______|____________|________________|__________________|
1     |   php      |   2013-01-01   |  2013-01-21      |
2     |   C        |   2013-12-01   |  2013-12-21      |
3     |   C++      |   2013-04-01   |  2013-04-21      |
4     |   C#       |   2013-06-01   |  2013-06-21      |
5     |   Mysql    |   2013-09-01   |  2013-09-21      |
```

Result like

```
    id    | subjects   |   from         |   to             |
    ______|____________|________________|__________________|
    1     |   C#       |   2013-06-01   |  2013-06-21      |
    2     |   Mysql    |   2013-09-01   |  2013-09-21      |
    3     |   C        |   2013-12-01   |  2013-12-21      |
    4     |   php      |   2013-01-01   |  2013-01-21      |
    5     |   C++      |   2013-04-01   |  2013-04-21      |
```

Comment: Get month value and subtract column with June month value and do order by this resulted column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving code in SQL Server you can do same in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
    BookID INT IDENTITY,
    AuthID INT,
    DAT DATETIME
)
GO

INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-60)
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-180)
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-30)
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-70)
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-270)
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(2, GETDATE()-360)

SELECT datename(month, DAT) AS MonthName,
               Month(DAT) AS MonthNum,
               CASE WHEN Month(DAT)-6 >0 
                    THEN Month(DAT)-6 
                    ELSE Month(DAT)+6 
               END AS ReqOrder,
               * 
 FROM Author 
 ORDER BY 3

DROP TABLE Author
```

Let me know your comments/results.